# Android JSON Call through HTTPPOST with Headers

Tags: java, android, json, rest, http-post

I found an example on how to call JSON from HTTPPOST in Android. Now I can call A service on my localhost using the link: (http://10.0.2.2/testingjson/testing.json)

It gives the output in the listView and that is Great!

Now what I need or require is that I want to insert some extra information on the link like,

```
http://10.0.2.2/testingjson/testing.json?regid=1234&pass="abcd"
```

There are two java Files, Main and JSONfunction.

Here is all the code:

Main.java:

```
    package com.android.jsontut;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;

    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;
    import org.w3c.dom.Document;
    import org.w3c.dom.Element;
    import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;



    import android.app.ListActivity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
    import android.widget.ListAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
    import android.widget.Toast;

public class Main extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listplaceholder);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


        JSONObject json = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://10.0.2.2/testingjson/testing.json");

        try{

            JSONArray  earthquakes = json.getJSONArray("earthquakes");

            for(int i=0;i<earthquakes.length();i++){                        
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    
                JSONObject e = earthquakes.getJSONObject(i);

                map.put("id",  String.valueOf(i));
                map.put("name", "Earthquake name:" + e.getString("eqid"));
                map.put("magnitude", "Magnitude: " +  e.getString("magnitude"));
                mylist.add(map);            
            }       
        }catch(JSONException e)        {
             Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
        }

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist , R.layout.main, 
                        new String[] { "name", "magnitude" }, 
                        new int[] { R.id.item_title, R.id.item_subtitle });

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        final ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);  
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {              
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);                   
                Toast.makeText(Main.this, "ID '" + o.get("id") + "' was clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Now the Second File:

JSONFUNCTIONS.java

```
package com.android.jsontut;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.HashMap;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONfunctions {

    public static JSONObject getJSONfromURL(String url){
        InputStream is = null;
        String result = "";
        JSONObject jArray = null;

        //http post
        try{
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();

        }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
        }

      //convert response to string
        try{
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                result=sb.toString();
        }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
        }

        try{

            jArray = new JSONObject(result);            
        }catch(JSONException e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
        }

        return jArray;
    }
}
```

Is there any complete Example from where I can learn how to add Header in this example? or can any genius help me? :)

I am willing to solve this problem so I will be happy to talk in detail to solve this issue! :)

Please let me know if need more information..

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you truly want to use POST you need to create a NameValuePair object and populate it with your parameters.

```
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("regid", "123"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", "abcd"));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

But I suspect that since you are only GETting a JSON object you don't actually want to use HttpPost objects to make your request.  Look at HttpGet instead which will allow you to use the url as you have posted (http://10.0.0.2/some/url?param=123&otherparam=456).  You can still read the response the same way.

Comment: Thanks!
I wanted to use HTTPOST because it is Secure.
This is simple example, but what I am asked to do is to use HTTPPOST and use header.

Can you please mention that where I can add this above code in my example? :)

Answer (score 1):

I am confused about whether you want to put this on the query string or in a header.  A query string variable would go right at the end of the URL (e.g. http://10.0.2.2/testingjson/testing.json?regid=1234&pass="abcd")

As for headers looks like the HttpPost class has an inherited **[addHeader()](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/message/AbstractHttpMessage.html?is-external=true#addHeader%28org.apache.http.Header%29)** method.

So it would go something like:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
httpPost.addHeader(new BasicHeader("regid", "1234"));
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any service from where I can send header and get response to test my program?
I want to use HTTPPost, the working will be like.. User will be asked to write registration id and password, this registration id and password will be requested to the webservice and then the service will response with yes or no..

Comment: I want to use Header not Query string.

Comment: I dont know of any web services that echo your request headers.  You may have to write your own small web application to do that.

Comment: Ok Thanks!
Can you please give suggestion that the above code I have shown is correct and what other changes do I need to make after inserting this code:
    httpPost.addHeader(new BasicHeader("regid", "1234));

Sorry for a dumb question

Comment: It really seems like you are abusing HTTP.  Headers aren't really for parameters.  HttpPost isn't any more secure than HttpGet.  It depends on how you send the data.  You want security then you should be using HTTPS.

Comment: Thanks @Nkijak!
I got the answer, I was confused before. I just added the NameValueParameter to the Post and it works great!

On this line:
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

Does it mean that we have encoded the parameters?
Because the next step will be to encode the data and send to the server.

Many Thanks!